# How to run psexec from a TFS invokeProcess task

Tags: tfs, build, psexec

I'm having problems running psexec from a TFS invokeProcess task.

My invokeProcess looks like this:
http://www.bjesklauget.dk/images/memberImages/psexec_task.png

But my output looks like this:

http://www.bjesklauget.dk/images/memberImages/psexec_tfs.png

How can I succesfully run the psexec.exe in my invokeProcess task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The TFS build-service user did not have the proper access rights to the target server. I was led astray by the "other errors and warnings" messages. Even thought it works now, these messages and the 'stop'-icons still appear.